# c# And/Or vb.net equivalent of apache commons Validate

Tags: java, c#, vb.net

In Java, if [Apache Commons Lang](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang) jar is in the classpath, we can do one line [Validates](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/Validate.html%20Validates), like

```
Validate.isTrue(someBoolean, "This should be true");
```

In effect the above is the same as:

```
if (! someBoolean) {
    throw new RuntimeException("This should be true");
}
```

Is there something in the .net world that will do the same?
I know I have seen code somewhere that did something similar but I can't remember where or the systax.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Something like this: `int val == 5 ? "true" : "false";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can, of course, write your own:

```
public static class Validate 
{
    public static void IsTrue(bool value) 
    {
        if (!value) throw new InvalidOperationException(message)
    }
}
```

Also, in C# or VB you can use code contracts:

```
Contract.Requires(someBoolean, "This should be true")
```

This requires downloading the [code contracts extension](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/1ec7db13-3363-46c9-851f-1ce455f66970) from the [Visual Studio extensions site](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/). You can turn on code contracts and have them verified at compile time, and it allows specifying fairly arbitrary contract conditions.

Comment: Yes!  Contract is what I had in mind.  I had seen it somewhere but I could not remember it. Thanks!

Comment: Started an initial port at https://github.com/christoforosl/Validate/blob/master/Validate.cs